# Sort a list of servers by fastest ping time with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In my Electron app I have a list of server addresses that I need to sort by shortest response time. I have a function that needs the sorted list:

```
function start() {
    // first step, get list of servers
    var servers_sorted = get_sorted_list_of_servers();

    // rest of function
}
```

Then I have a function that iterates through the list of servers:

```
function get_sorted_list_of_servers() {
    // access unsorted list from file

    unsorted_servers.forEach((server) => {
        // Get ping times for each server
        // Here is where I am stuck
    });

    // Sort based on ping times....

    return sorted_list_of_servers;
}
```

The problem is that I'm not sure how to get the ping time for each server. I've found a couple of libraries that wrap the `ping` utility ([net-ping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/net-ping) and [ping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping)). However, they use callbacks (which makes sense given that pinging a server can take a minute) and I need some way of getting a list of the server times.

```
// From ping example code
unsorted_servers.forEach(function (server) {
    ping.promise.probe(host).then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        // Update a global variable here??
    });
});
```

I've thought about letting the callbacks update a global list but then I need some way of signalling once all the servers have been tested.

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Once you have an `async` operation, eveything up the chain also has to be `async`..    So a calling a function like -> `var servers_sorted = get_sorted_list_of_servers();` is never going to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all` and `map` to loop over your server list and wait for all of the Promises to resolve. Here's a quick example using ping:

```js
const sortBy = require('lodash.sortby');
const ping = require('ping');

const servers = ['google.com', 'facebook.com', 'amazon.com', 'apple.com'];

Promise.all(servers.map(server => ping.promise.probe(server))).then(response => {
  console.log(sortBy(response, 'time'))
});
```

Here's an React demo using Promise.all and rendering the results:

https://server-ping-fuupenayzp.now.sh/

and the source

https://zeit.co/rusty-dev/server-ping/fuupenayzp/source?f=src/App.js